# Next value in a column, less than or equal to difference from current value

Tags: r

I want to retrieve the value from one column, based on the values in another column. I have included an example which should help explain.

For this example, if we say that we want to return the value in `index` where the next value in `number` is less than or equal to the current number-10, we would get the column `ind_return`:

```
   index  number  ind_return
1      A     100           C
2      B     105           C
3      C      84          NA
4      D      90           G
5      E     120           F
6      F     110           G
7      G      75          NA



df <- data.frame(index = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"),
             number = c(100, 105, 84,  90,  120, 110,  75))
```

The question is, how can we get `ind_return`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `outer` to get the differences. Exclude from that the `upper.tri` and the `diag` and then get the row using `which` in `apply`.

```
i <- outer(df$number, df$number, "-")
i[upper.tri(i)] <- NA
diag(i) <- NA
df$index[apply(i < -9, 2, function(x) which(x)[1])]
#[1] "C" "C" NA  "G" "F" "G" NA
```

Or making the comparison in a `sapply` loop

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
  df$index[i+which(df$number[i+seq_len(nrow(df)-i)] - df$number[i] < -9)[1]]
})
#[1] "C" "C" NA  "G" "F" "G" NA
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution in `tidyverse` . As a description of how my solution works:

- It's basically a row-wise operation and in every iteration we remove the previous values of both `index` and `number` variables through `-c(seq(.y - 1))`
- Since we iterate over 2 variables here I chose `map2` function from package `purrr`. Here `.x` represents the corresponding value of our first variable `index` in every row and `.y` equals to the corresponding value of the second variable `number`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(ind_return = 
           map2_chr(number, id, ~ df$index[-c(seq(.y - 1))][which(df$number[-c(seq(.y - 1))] <= .x - 10)][1]))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  index number    id ind_return
  <chr>  <dbl> <int> <chr>     
1 A        100     1 C         
2 B        105     2 C         
3 C         84     3 NA        
4 D         90     4 G         
5 E        120     5 F         
6 F        110     6 G         
7 G         75     7 NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another version using `dplyr` and `purrr`, which I think is slightly more legible than [Anoushiravan R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67968737/2884859)'s:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

filter_it <- function(the_letter){
  df %>% 
    filter(index >= the_letter) %>% 
    filter(number <= .$number[1] - 10) -> filtered
  
  ifelse(nrow(filtered) == 0, NA, filtered$index[1])
}

df %>% 
  mutate(ind_return = map_chr(index, filter_it))


  index number ind_return
1     A    100          C
2     B    105          C
3     C     84       <NA>
4     D     90          G
5     E    120          F
6     F    110          G
7     G     75       <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

All the answers proposed are fantastic.  However, I would have done it like this-

- use `map2` with `number` as first arg and `row_number()` as second
- store intermediate result of difference of current row's `number` with whole `number` vector in `x` (say)
- check which of `x` are `>= 10` and retrieve all corresponding `index`
- extract its tail with `n() - .y` elements
- take out its first element and store in another intermediate `z` (say)
- finally check if `z` is empty to replace it with `NA`

```r
df <- data.frame(index = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"),
                 number = c(100, 105, 84,  90,  120, 110,  75))
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(ind_return = map2(number, row_number(), ~ {y <- .x - number; 
                        z <- head(tail(index[y >= 10], n() - .y), 1); 
                        if(is_empty(z)) NA else z}))

#>   index number ind_return
#> 1     A    100          C
#> 2     B    105          C
#> 3     C     84         NA
#> 4     D     90          G
#> 5     E    120          F
#> 6     F    110          G
#> 7     G     75         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>